# Как отправить картинку через ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, form

Суть в том, что на страницу **save.php** посылается `POST` запрос с картинкой и парочкой полей, а на странице `main.html`, с которой это сделали (`form target="_blank"` - присутствует на форме) выполняется:

```
$('#obj_d').html('Сохранено успешно');
```

Думаю можно как-то отправить картинку через `$.ajax()`, но не знаю как.
`ID` картинки `cat_img_t`. Что делает PHP: скрипт в файле **save.php** ловит картинку, изменяет размер, кодирует в `base64` и заносит в БД. Как отправить картинку через **ajax**?

Comment: Такое чувство, будто вы не полностью вопрос написали: на какую страницу отправляется? Как отправляется? (вообще js не может закрывать вкладки программно)

Comment: Что закрыть и что куда отправить? Поясните

Comment: *на эту страницу посылается POST запрос* - обычно `POST`-запрос посылается со страницы, обычно для передачи данных на сервер, будь то данные с формы или файл, ну да ладно. Теперь перейдем к сообщению *на хосте два файлика main.html и save.php* - так, они есть, это уже не плохо. Как я понимаю, данные со страницы `main.html` передаются в `save.php`, верно? Что далее, что у Вас происходит и что не нужно открывать или закрыть?

Comment: Правку увидел в вопросе. Да, можно, сейчас ответ напишу

Answer (score 11, accepted):

На отправку данных с формы пишем обработчик:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#-идентификатор формы написать сюда-').on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // делаем отмену действия браузера и формируем ajax
        var formData = new FormData($('#-идентификатор формы написать сюда-')[0]);
        // данные с формы завернем в переменную для ajax

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST', // тип запроса
            url: $(this).attr('action'), // куда будем отправлять, можно явно указать
            data:formData, // данные, которые передаем
            cache:false, // кэш и прочие настройки писать именно так (для файлов)
            // (связано это с кодировкой и всякой лабудой)
            contentType: false, // нужно указать тип контента false для картинки(файла)
            processData: false, // для передачи картинки(файла) нужно false 
            success:function(data){ // в случае успешного завершения
                console.log("Завершилось успешно"); // выведем в консоли успех 
                console.log(data); // и что в ответе получили, если там что-то есть
            },
            error: function(data){ // в случае провала
                console.log("Завершилось с ошибкой"); // сообщение об ошибке
                console.log(data); // и данные по ошибке в том числе
            }
        });
    }));  
});
```

Кстати, для `url` по идее можно оставить вот так, если изначально все правильно вызывается:

```
url: this.action,
```

Либо написать явный путь `url`, как Вам удобнее.

А еще, к примеру, если Вам нужно вызвать отправку данных с формы после выбора Вашей картинки, то после выбора можете написать вот это:

```
$("#-идентификатор формы написать сюда-").submit();
```

> **Атрибут target** - после того, как обработчик формы получает данные, он возвращает
>   результат в виде HTML-документа. Вы можете определить окно, в которое
>   будет загружаться итоговая веб-страница. Для этого используется
>   атрибут target, в качестве его значения используется имя окна или
>   фрейма. Если target не установлен, возвращаемый результат показывается
>   в текущем окне.

У Вас в коде написано:

> `form target="_blank"` - загружает страницу в новое окно браузера.

Если не хотите новых страниц - уберите просто аттрибут и все. Вы переделаете на `ajax` и никаких вкладок не будет, при желании можете сделать скрытый `<div class="hidden"...`, в который будете что-то писать, к примеру *"Файл успешно загружен"* или ошибку какую-то и потом в зависимости от результата внутри `success` и `error` отображать нужные данные  в этом блоке и убирать у него `hidden` через `.removeClass('hidden');`.

По поводу `jQuery.ajax` можно почитать вот тут: [Description jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), правда описание на английском, но это не так страшно.

Comment: Вы используете FormData(this). У меня на странице энное кол-во форм. Можно в formdata отправить только с формы с определённым id, class или name?

Comment: Да, можно по id, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Хочу ещё вопросик задать. У меня все inputы повылазили из form.

Comment: @Дмитрий, Вам нужно было убрать `target` у формы и задать для нее id, ну и обработчик отправки данных с формы написать по примеру, который я написал. Что и куда повылазило, не понимаю, поясните. Может Вы где-то лишнего убрали?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Fe1Bl внутри таблицы хотел форму запихнуть и в td по inputу, но даже если я через инспектор в форму поле добавлю, то браузер его оттуда выкидывает

Comment: Вы мне на скриншоте показываете то, как получается, а как изначально? Нужен код `html`, чтобы понять, что у Вас не так.

Comment: @Дмитрий, СТОП. Вы это делаете в браузере, через просмотр кода, через инструменты разработчика??? о_О

Comment: Нет. Вот код: http://pastebin.com/nnbuzU1G. AJAX грузит страницу с этим кодом и выводит в div

Comment: @Дмитрий, а Вы не хотите обернуть строку формой? То есть `<form...` а потом уже внутри `<tr>`? Или так тоже не работает? JS можно переписать под новую логику

Comment: Так не работает

Comment: @Дмитрий, форма не может быть внутри таблицы [Form inside a table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5967613/5275890)

Comment: @Дмитрий, Вы можете разместить всю таблицу внутри формы. Вы можете разместить форму внутри ячейки таблицы. Вы не можете разместить часть таблицы внутри формы. Как-то так.

Comment: Хм.. И как быть?

Comment: @Дмитрий, ну там в ответе есть решение - форма поверх всей таблицы. Почитайте, я дал ссылку, либо задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: new FormData это конечно замечательно, но есть большой минус для Iphone 6+ к сожалению не работает и будет проблема с такими пользователями.

Comment: Отсюда вопрос знает кто нибудь как отправить картинку через ajax, но чтоб работало и на Iphone 6+?

Comment: @AlexSavenkov ну так задайте новый вопрос. Покажите ваш код, покажите вашу проблему (конкретную, а не надуманную), тогда и будет ответ. В текущем виде ваши комментарии являются неуместными.