# Передача файла при помощи AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, fileupload, webrtc

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача, получить видео при помощи [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/), записать его, и отправить на сервер, для последующего сохранения.

Удаётся записать видео м вэб-камеры, удаётся это видео скачать, но не понимаю, как передать его на сервер.

Изначально пытался передать содержимое в инпут и сделать сабмит формы, но понял, что так [нельзя](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp).

Теперь пытаюсь сделать то же самое, через AJAX, и тоже не получается, т.к. передаётся строка с названием, а не сам файл.

Если пытаюсь так:

```
function send() {
  var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        'video': superBuffer,
        'csrftoken': csrftoken,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  });
}
```

то получаю такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.
```

А вот пример функции для скачивания:

```
function download() {
  var blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = blob;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
}
```

Здесь всё работает хорошо, но основная задача, передать на сервер.

Comment: Ссылка на ответ с небольшими пояснениями в коде: [Как отправить картинку через ajax?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624598/189339)

Answer (score 3):

На оригинальном stackoverflow рекомендуют добавить в параметры ajax-запроса `processData: false, contentType: false` - [Submitting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722920/submitting-a-file-with-jquery-ajax-gives-typeerror)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал так:

```
function send() {
  var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("filename", 'test.webm');
  formdata.append('data', superBuffer);
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    method: 'post',
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false,
    data: formdata,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    },
  });
}
```

Всё работает.

Спасибо за подсказку @Leo240

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="upload">
  <input type="file" name="myfile">
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</form>

<script>
  document.forms.upload.onsubmit = function() {
    var input = this.elements.myfile;
    var file = input.files[0];
    if (file) {
      upload(file);
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Мы получаем файл из формы через свойство `files` элемента `<input>` и передаём его в функцию `upload`:

```
function upload(file) {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // обработчик для закачки
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
    log(event.loaded + ' / ' + event.total);
  }

  // обработчики успеха и ошибки
  // если status == 200, то это успех, иначе ошибка
  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      log("success");
    } else {
      log("error " + this.status);
    }
  };

  xhr.open("POST", "upload", true);
  xhr.send(file);

}
```

Этот код отправит файл на сервер и будет сообщать о прогрессе при его закачке (xhr.upload.onprogress), а также об окончании запроса (xhr.onload, xhr.onerror).

**Если нужно дополнительно передать имя файла или что-то ещё** – это можно удобно сделать через форму, при помощи объекта `FormData`:

Создадим форму `formData` и прибавим к ней поле с файлом `file` и именем `"myfile"`:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myfile", file);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Данные будут отправлены в кодировке `multipart/form-data`. Серверный фреймворк увидит это как обычную форму с файлом, практически все серверные технологии имеют их встроенную поддержку. Индикация прогресса реализуется точно так же.

[взято от сюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress)

Comment: Дело в том, что в сам input никто файл не засовывает.

Comment: это пример. кто мешает самому отправить? ajax запросом сформировал и кинул на сервер.