# Вывод значения переменной из js в переменную php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как вывести значение переменной из js в php?

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("userfile").files[0].name;
```

PHP:

```
$result = значение var;
echo $result;
```

Comment: передать из клиента на сервер посредством ajax

Comment: Можно привести пример кода?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418608/191482 ......... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/381954/191482   ........  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624598/191482   ......

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием `jQuery` как-то так.

```js
 $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'filename='+$('#userfile').prop('files')[0].name,
            error: function(req, text, error) {
                alert('Ajax Error:'+error);  
            },
            success: function ( msg) {
               //тут обработка ответа сервера в случае удачной передачи данных
            },
        });
```

```php
<?php
//script.php

if ( count( $_POST ) > 0 && isset( $_POST['filename'] ) ) {
    $result = $_POST['filename'];
    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код JS выполняется на фронте в браузере, после отработки бэкенда. Так что в том же самом скрипте вы его никак не получите. Если не сделать только релоад страницы, перед этим отправив запрос через Ajax и записав данные в базу или в сессию например. А потом это подтянуть в php-скрипте. Но это какой-то сломанный велосипед...